# How to get third-party app session data from a Symfony2 app?

Tags: php, symfony

In order to implement cross application authentication (getting logged in in my Symfony2 app if the user already logged in in an other application), I made a Symfony2 listener class that checks if specific data concerning the user is in the session. This data comes from a non-Symfony2 (but PHP) app.

The problem is that the session data from the other app is not present in the session object I use in my class.

Here is the listener (simplified) class:

```
<?php
class OldAppAuthenticationListener
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            // don't do anything if it's not the master request
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->context->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $session = $request->getSession();

            $userName = $session->get('nomUtilisateur');

            $token = new PreAuthenticatedToken($userName, null, 'secured_area', array('ROLE_USER'));

            $session->set('_security_secured_area',  serialize($token));
        }
    }
}
```

It is registered in services.yml like this:

```
services:
    my_app.listener.old_app_authentication:
        class: Acme\MyAppBundle\Listener\MyAppAuthenticationListener
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

But the `$session->get('nomUtilisateur')` always returns NULL (and `$session->all()` and `$_SESSION` only return some Symfony2 specific vars) although the other app stores all this data in the session.

Of course, I use the same cookie session domain for both apps (as configured in config.yml) and I can easily check that the PHPSESSID is the same.

So here is my question: why are the old app session variables not available and how can I get them from my listener class?

Comment: So can you see in dev tools / firebug etc that both apps are using the same domain for their session cookie? I would not have thought this would be the case - even if there is a sub domain then they will not match. When I did something similar I had to set a specific cookie by name, and retrieved by name in the second app. Or is this what you have done?

Comment: Yes, I can see that both apps use the same domain in dev tools (like Firebug). Each app uses the same domain for the cookie session (here: .localhost.com) and each app is on a specific subdomain (oldapp.localhost.com / acme.localhost.com). I configured the domain to use in config.yml (session  cookie_domain: localhost.com). Unfortunately I can't change the old app cookie name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-data-management), Symfony2 uses session bags to store session stuff. This means that you have to directly access the `$_SESSION` superglobal for such a functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing, and I forgot to update my question! Your answer is the right one!

Comment: Hope you don't use 2.2 and PHP 5.4 as I do, as for that you will need to do a LOT of tricks to achieve it...

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.2 (but with PHP 5.3) and don't have any issue so far! Wait and see! I'll give you updates if I have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use directly the php session fonctions.
also I had to check if session name, domain and save path are the same on both applications.

In my symfony I had to add:
    session_save_path('c:/wamp/tmp');
    session_name(_SESSION_ID_);
    session_start();
and then use $_SESSION

an other way that was given to me, but I didn't use is to use the sessions files directly like this:
"The trick was using the session cookie sent by the browser.

For example, an old web application, written in PHP, sent a cookie
called IntranetSession to the browser. As I knew where does PHP store
the session files, I simply opened that file, and decoded its contents
with session_decode(). The drawbacks of this is that session_decode()
puts its output directly into $_SESSION, overwriting you current
session data (even the stuff put there by Symfony). Basically the rule
is as follows:

```
$sessionData = file_get_contents($sessionFile);<br>
$tmpSess = $_SESSION;<br>
session_decode($sessionData);<br>
$otherAppSession = $_SESSION;<br>
$_SESSION = $tmpSess;<br>
```

"
hope this helps!